# Migrating to Linux from Windows

Tags: python, windows, linux

I have a python gui that access files on windows as C:\data and C:\MyDIR all outside my doc's.
On, a linux sys i created /data and /MyDIR.

My gui cant access. I foresee always using C:\data and C:\MyDIR on both systems.

How do I fix code or Linux permissions to have access to both dir and sub directories.

Answer (score 5):

Chmod is your friend.

However I question your design. Why do you want to have priviledges at such high levels of file systems. You know every user has a home dir and ther is always dir for configuration on both Windows and Linux.

**What you do is a bad practice.**

Comment: thanks not worried about bad practice. I want the directories on the systems to match. I dont want my files in Windows "My Documents" directories.

Comment: The directories on both systems can't "match" because paths work differently on both platforms. If you want to have a portable application, you need to use portable code, and that involves finding the corresponding paths for each platform.

Comment: ok, How do i write portable code "for directories" on both win and linux. I will have to re-write the Win code which working now.

Comment: Look at @Rosh Oxymoron's answer. You'll have to use different code for different OS's. You can't expect the directory file systems to "just match".

Answer (score 5):

Place the data in the directory Python considers to be the user's home directory on either platform.

```
home = os.path.expanduser('~')
datadir = os.path.join(home, '.yourappname')
```

If you don't like prefixing the name with a dot, you might consider using something like this instead:

```
home = os.path.expanduser('~')
if os.name == 'posix':
    datadir = os.path.join(home, '.yourappname')
else:
    datadir = os.path.join(home, 'Your App Name')
```

(Also some applications don't use `~/.yourappname` any more on Unix-like operating systems, and there is preference for `~/.local/share/yourappname`:  `os.path.join(home, '.local', 'share', 'yourappname')`.)

The important thing to remember is: put it somewhere in the directory that `'~'` expands to, and include the name of your app in it to avoid clashes with the data directories of other apps.

Comment: There's also a fair number of applications using `~/.config/appname/`

Comment: `~/.config/appname/` is presumably for configuration, while `~/.local/share/appname/` is for data. However `os.environ['XDG_CONFIG_HOME']` and `os.environ['XDG_DATA_HOME']` should presumably be used instead if available. Maybe `data_home = os.environ.get('XDG_DATA_HOME', os.path.join(home, '.local', 'share')); datadir = os.path.join(data_home, 'yourappname')` is the most correct way to select a path for your data dir.

Comment: I was think along the lines of ....if OS is Windows then use codeset1 else use codeset2. Codeset1 contains variables for windows. Codeset2 conatins variables for Linux....Any help with this usage. Codeset1 or 2 could be in program/Files/database/etc.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, maybe you meant to say /data and /MyDIR.

Second, they're direct children of /, the root filesystem, which is reserved to the superuser (root) and people who know what they're doing.
Unfortunately the Windows world doesn't enforce nor encourage good practices, so you were able to create those two directories in your C: root (pretty much the analogue of the / directory). Long story short, it's likely you had to use root (probably masked as sudo) to make those two directories inside /, which means root is their owner, and it (and only it) has the permission to write inside them.

You'd better create some alike dirs inside your home (cd ~ and you're there) using your regular user (because you *have* a regular user, haven't you?) and then use them.

On the other hand you could use something like fuse and ntfs-3g to access those two dirs in the original ntfs filesystem corresponding to C:

Answer (score 1):

The linux filesystem uses / as root. You can't use \data and \MyDir because \ does not mean anything. Moreover, the default owner of / is the user named root. Commonly you work with a different user than root on the machine.

So by default, you don't have the permission to write or to create something in / .

Choose another directory in your home directory. For example :

~/data/ & ~/MyDir/

~/ equals to /home/user428862/ where user428862 is your username on the machine.

Answer (score 1):

> i created \data and \MyDIR

First, no you didn't. Paths use `/` in linux, not `\`.

Second, do NOT create directories in the root directory unless you know exactly what you're doing. True, you're not going to hurt anything by doing this, but it's extremely bad practice and should be avoided except for specific cases.

Linux is a multi-user OS. If you have configuration files that the user can write to, they should be in the user's home directory somewhere. If you have config files that are read only, they should be installed somewhere such as `/etc/`.

Comment: thanks. Linux may be a multi-user OS, But I'm only user. And, will always be the only owner.  I need RW directory on both Win and linux.

Comment: Linux doesn't care that you're the only user. That's not how it was designed. Since you're the only user, then just put the file in your `/home/username/` directory.

Answer (score 0):

Where did you create those directories in your Linux? Under $HOME? You can determine your path separator using the string 'sep' from the os module, that is, os.sep, then acct according to its return value. Comes to my mind sth like:

import os

dirs = [os.sep + "data", os.sep + "MyDIR"]

But all depends on what you want to do. If you can, please explain further your needs.